# How to return a matched object inside an array in mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

```
{
  "_id": 36546b46bbh343..,
  "name": "Mike",
  "Friends: [
    {"name":"lora","age":23},
    {"name":"test","age":26}
  ]
}
```

I know that if we do

```
dbname.find({
  Friends:{
    $elemMatch:{
      "name": "test", 
      "age": 26
    }
  }
})
```

It will return the whole document with all the objects. But what I have been searching for is there any method so that I can get only the object that matches it.

Comment: u're doing it correct, using `$elemMatch` is how, i dont see any problem

Comment: but why is it `dbname.find` instead of `someCollection.find`?

Comment: @datdinhquoc just had this in my mind. Anyways yes this query is correct but it returns the whole document in which the conditions match, whereas i want only the object that matches. Can you think of anything?

Comment: try the 'projection' option: http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.6/api/Collection.html#find

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 db.collection.find({
      Friends: {
        $elemMatch: {
          "name": "test",
          "age": 26
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "Friends.$": 1
    })
```

[Demo](https://mongoplayground.net/p/pCSafkDc4ap)

Comment: Your formatting is wrong -https://mongoplayground.net/p/U5Q4rMH3SDP

Comment: [see](https://mongoplayground.net/p/dEjzlFFY27Q) Added Comments